# Expect at least one argument for variadic method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a method like so:

```
  getValues(...args: Array<string>) : Array<any> {
    return args.map(k => {
      return this.shared.get(k);
    });
  }
```

I use the method like this:

```
const c = b.getValues(); // compiles
```

it's actually incorrect in my case to pass no arguments, it only makes sense if at least one argument is passed.

Is there a way to tell TypeScript that at least one argument needs to be passed?

Comment: `getValues(mandatoryArg: string, ...optionalArgs: Array<string>)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an overload that has a mandatory parameter to force callers to specify at least one value, but keep the implementation signature using just a rest parameter (keeping your implementation the same)

```
getValues(mandatory: string, ...args: Array<string>): Array<any>
getValues(...args: Array<string>): Array<any> {
    return args.map(k => {
        return this.shared.get(k);
    });
}
```

Comment: What about for plain functions that are not in a class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tuple-like array with variadic arguments:

```
getValues(...args: [string, ...string[]])
```

Comment: I know this is an old one, but it is `...args: [string, ...string[]]`, isn't it?

Comment: Good spot. I'm surprised nobody pointed this out until now. I'll edit my answer.