# TypeScript and ...args

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

TypeScript doesn't show "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0." error, when it should.

```
type PolyElement = [number, number];

export interface Node {
  element: PolyElement | null;
  next: Node | null;
}
```

```
export class Node {
  constructor(element?: PolyElement) {
    this.element = element ?? null;
    this.next = null;
  }
  add(...args: PolyElement[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
       //some code
      }
    }
  }
```

then I invoke method like so:

```
poly1.add([1,2,3]);
```

and it outputs: `Argument of type '[number, number, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PolyElement'. Types of property 'length' are incompatible. Type '3' is not assignable to type '2'.ts(2345)`

also

```
poly1.add([]);
```

outputs: `Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PolyElement'. Type '[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1ts(2345)`

etc.

The QUESTION is why:

```
poly1.add();
```

DOESN'T output something like: `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.` ?

Comment: Your answer is already in your question: `Argument of type '[]'...`. Empty array counts as an argument, it is just of the wrong type.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake when copying. I already corrected my question. Now it is 
` poly1.add();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expect at least one argument for variadic method in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374490/expect-at-least-one-argument-for-variadic-method-in-typescript)

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes, but there is a better reply to this question in this thread that in the other you linked

Comment: Yep, now there is! Ideally, the other questions should be linked to this newer one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax

```
add(...args: PolyElement[]) {
```

means "Pass me as many arguments (including zero) as you like".

You can write this instead to enforce at least one argument:

```
add(...args: [PolyElement, ...PolyElement[]]) {
```

Comment: could you help what is the best syntax to pass more than 0 arguments ot type PolyElement?

Comment: Maybe `add(el: PolyElement, ...args: PolyElement[])`? But you'd need to handle `el` explicitly.

Comment: In all honesty you got this before me.  I just added the bit to enforce at least 1 `PolyElement`.

Comment: That's the thing, you need to use it, if not, it means that you're explicitly ignoring the first parameter.

Comment: Now I prefer this answer (still upvoted both). And while looking for a duplicate candidate, didn't see anything similar.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh that's the syntax I was looking for. thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

Rest arguments `...` means 0 or more.  If you want at least 1, then you should explicitly accept a first argument and then accept "the rest".

```
type NumArr = [number, number];

// Forces at least 1 NumArr
const foo = (a: NumArr, ...b: NumArr[]) => {
    const all = [a, ...b];
    console.log(all);
}

const bar = () => {
    foo([1, 2]); // Good!
    foo([]); // Wrong type, [] is not [number, number]
    foo(); // Expected at least 1 arg
};
```